# Using int index where double is expected in C++ AMP retrict(direct3d) code

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, gpu, gpgpu, c++-amp

Googling didn’t help much, has anyone used AMP?

In the code snippet below the cast from integer to double (double v = idx.x) leads to a “Failed to create shader” run time error.
I thought the restrict(direct3d) would have alerted me of things the GPU won’t be able to handle during compile time.
Is there an alternative to pow() – or will I have to write a loop to do that?

```
concurrency::array_view<double,1> prices = …
concurrency::parallel_for_each(
   prices.grid, [=](index<1> idx) mutable restrict(direct3d) {
      double v = idx.x;
      prices[idx] =  concurrency::pow(u, v);
…
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's really the cast that's causing the problem? I tend to doubt it. What happens when you just evaluate `idx.x`, throw the result away and set `double v = 2.502907875`?

Comment: double v = 2.502907875 would work. Actually what I needed was prices[idx] = concurrency::pow(u, idx.x) and it would give that excepion.

Comment: By the way, I am trying this under an emulation.

Answer (score 1):

please see our explanation of double support for GPUs on Windows, and also the C++ AMP math library
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/02/08/math-library-for-c-amp.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/02/07/double-precision-support-in-c-amp.aspx

If you still have a question, feel free to post back. Also please tag your questions with c++amp so we have a better chance of finding them.